# Elasticsearch Query DSL multiple "query"s

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

This works:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "EventID": "4732"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But how can I add multiple such "query"s together? For example, `"EventID": "4732"` or `"EventID": "4728"`

In practise the queries are more complex, based on Sigma rules, otherwise I know I could do:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "data.win.system.eventID": "4732"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "data.win.system.eventID": "4728"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

The output from Sigma would be of the format:

```json
[
    {
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "EventID": "4732"
                }
                }
            ]
            }
        }
        }
    }
    },
    {
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                "match_phrase": {
                    "EventID": "4728"
                }
                }
            ]
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
]
```

However, this gives me:

`[parsing_exception] unknown query [query], with { line=1 & col=1065 }`

And doesn't work in Dev Tools at all. In the Discover section, it is is automatically converted to:

```
{
  "0": {
    "query": {
      "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "EventID": "4732"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "query": {
      "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "EventID": "4728"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which in Dev Tools gives:

`"reason" : "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [0].",`

Research suggested to wrap the "query"s in a query bool should, i.e.:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
        "query": {
            "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "EventID": "4732"
                    }
                    }
                ]
                }
            }
            }
        }
        },
        {
        "query": {
            "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "EventID": "4728"
                    }
                    }
                ]
                }
            }
            }
        }
        }
    ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

This also gives gives:

`[parsing_exception] unknown query [query], with { line=1 & col=1065 }`

or, in Dev Tools:

`"reason" : "unknown query [query]"`

Is it possible to do multiple "query"s?

Example of Sigma script I want to convert:

```
[
  {
    "query": {
      "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* -NoP *"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* -W Hidden *"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* -decode *"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* /decode *"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* -e* JAB*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* -e* SUVYI*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* -e* SQBFAFgA*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* -e* aWV4I*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* -e* IAB*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* -e* PAA*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* -e* aQBlAHgA*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "*vssadmin delete shadows*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "*reg SAVE HKLM\\\\SAM*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* -ma *"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "*Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\CurrentVersion\\\\Run*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "*.downloadstring(*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "*.downloadfile(*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* /ticket:*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* sekurlsa*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* p::d *"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "*;iex(*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "*schtasks* /create *AppData*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* comsvcs.dll,MiniDump*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "CommandLine.keyword": "* comsvcs.dll,#24*"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "ParentImage.keyword": "*\\\\WINWORD.EXE*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "ParentImage.keyword": "*\\\\EXCEL.EXE*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "ParentImage.keyword": "*\\\\POWERPNT.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "ParentImage.keyword": "*\\\\MSPUB.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "ParentImage.keyword": "*\\\\VISIO.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "ParentImage.keyword": "*\\\\OUTLOOK.EXE*"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\cmd.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\powershell.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\wscript.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\cscript.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\schtasks.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\scrcons.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\regsvr32.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\hh.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\wmic.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\mshta.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\msiexec.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\forfiles.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\AppData\\\\*"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\apache*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\tomcat*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\w3wp.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\php-cgi.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\nginx.exe*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "Image.keyword": "*\\\\httpd.exe*"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "should": [
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "CommandLine.keyword": "*whoami*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "CommandLine.keyword": "*net user *"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "CommandLine.keyword": "*ping -n *"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "CommandLine.keyword": "*systeminfo*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "CommandLine.keyword": "*&cd&echo*"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "wildcard": {
                              "CommandLine.keyword": "*cd /d *"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "Image.keyword": "*\\\\whoami.exe*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "match_phrase": {
                        "User": "NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "query": {
      "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "EventLog": "Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon"
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "match_phrase": {
                              "EventID": "11"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "bool": {
                              "should": [
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "TargetFilename.keyword": "*.dmp*"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "TargetFilename.keyword": "*Desktop\\\\how*"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "TargetFilename.keyword": "*Desktop\\\\decrypt*"
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "bool": {
                              "should": [
                                {
                                  "match_phrase": {
                                    "EventID": "12"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "match_phrase": {
                                    "EventID": "13"
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "bool": {
                              "should": [
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "TargetObject.keyword": "*UserInitMprLogonScript*"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "TargetObject.keyword": "*\\\\CurrentVersion\\\\Image File Execution Options\\\\*"
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "bool": {
                              "should": [
                                {
                                  "match_phrase": {
                                    "EventID": "12"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "match_phrase": {
                                    "EventID": "13"
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "bool": {
                              "should": [
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "TargetObject.keyword": "*\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\CurrentVersion\\\\Run\\\\*"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "TargetObject.keyword": "*\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\CurrentVersion\\\\RunOnce\\\\*"
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "bool": {
                              "should": [
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "Details.keyword": "*AppData*"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "Details.keyword": "*\\\\Users\\\\Public\\\\*"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "Details.keyword": "*\\\\Temp\\\\*"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "Details.keyword": "*powershell*"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "Details.keyword": "*wscript*"
                                  }
                                },
                                {
                                  "wildcard": {
                                    "Details.keyword": "*cscript*"
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "query": {
      "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "EventID": "7045"
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "ServiceName.keyword": "*WCESERVICE*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "ServiceName.keyword": "*WCE SERVICE*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "ServiceName.keyword": "*winexesvc*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "ServiceName.keyword": "*DumpSvc*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "ServiceName.keyword": "*pwdump*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "ServiceName.keyword": "*gsecdump*"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "ServiceName.keyword": "*cachedump*"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest for what you want to do would be like this using a `terms` query (which has OR semantics):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "EventID": [
              "4732", "4728"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is it doesn't work for more complex scripts. I've added the `godmode` example to my initial post.

Comment: Wow, that query is the perfect anti-pattern: plenty of wildcard queries with leading wildcard, one of the biggest performance hoggers. You should really investigate the [`wildcard` field type](https://www.elastic.co/blog/find-strings-within-strings-faster-with-the-new-elasticsearch-wildcard-field)

Comment: It's not one I wrote myself, it's a demo Sigma rule. Yes, that specific one has a lot of `wildcard`s, but others don't. That's just an example for multiple `"query"`s :)